# For migrations without downtime, are default values or nullable columns always required?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, migration

Here is an example:

You create a new column called `note` on the `payments` table on `v1.1.0` (green) of your application. However, you notice a bug. You roll your application back to `v1.0.0` (blue). When `v1.0.0` creates a new payment, the database will throw an error because the `note` field is missing. However, if the `note` was nullable or had a database default, this would not happen.

Thus, am I correct in thinking that as long as "blue" (`v1.0.0`) could be rolled back to (i.e. in one release behind), every column must be added with either a default or nullable value? I assume that in the next release, say `v1.0.2`, you could then add a default value without risk?

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to rollback schema migrations, then yes, your schema must be backwards-compatible to whatever application version(s) you want to allow rollbacks to. Your policy only works if your application *never* assumes column count and order, i.e. never uses `SELECT *` directly on tables and always specifies the columns you are providing data for in any `INSERT` statement.

This policy will paint you into a corner fairly quickly. Think about what happens if you roll out a change, roll it back, then want to roll forward again. Your new column is now inconsistent, and you will have to spend time making it consistent again before the new code can go live.

(Dropping/nullable-ing a column is a fast action on modern PostgreSQL. On PG11 and later, adding a default value is also fast.)

Comment: So @dwhitemv  is your recommendation to add a default or nullable for each column? I think that is what you are saying, but I do not want to misinterpret! Or are you saying it makes more sense to simply drop the column when rolling back?

Comment: Drop the column.